# How do I declare a user defined attribute in version 0.9.1

Tags: scala.js

I am trying to migrate from version 0.8.1 to 0.9.1 in Scala js. Previously, if I wanted to have a user defined attribute in an element I did so as follows:

```
button("my-attribute".attr = "false")
```

But does no longer compiles in version 0.9.1. What is the correct approach now?

Comment: Scala.js doesn't have either versions 0.8.1 or 0.9.1.  Are you maybe thinking about a library that *uses* Scala.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what library you were using, but it almost looks like ScalaTags. If so, the syntax you want is:

```
button(attr("my-attribute") := "false")
```

[ScalaTags Docs](http://www.lihaoyi.com/scalatags/#CustomAttributes,Styles,TagNames)

I vaguely recall that ScalaTags used to have the `.attr` syntax you describe – it definitely looks familiar, but I can't find it right now. Maybe it was removed... And it is definitely `:=`, not `=`.

Also, the only relevant library I know where 0.9.1 is a relevant version number is [scala-js-dom](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom), but that library doesn't provide anything like the example you're describing.

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to mention it is scala-js-dom I am using. I found after that you can also wrap it use Attr() which is presumably essentially the same thing